# Нужна запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

> Конечно, будь начальник с ними до сих пор, они бы додумались до всего быстрее, но(,) пока меня не было, бедняга умер трагической смертью...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это часто встречающиеся сложные предложения, в которых имеется стык двух союзов (в данном предложении стык союзов "но" и "пока"). В таком случае запятая ставится, если дальше нет второй части составного союза  "пока...то". В этом предложении такой второй части нет (но, пока меня не было, бедняга умер трагической смертью...). Если бы предложение выглядело так: "но, пока меня не было,ТО бедняга умер трагической смертью"- в таком случае запятая между "но" и "пока" не ставилась бы. Для проверки правильности применения данного правила рекомендуют проделать процедуру, изложенную Людмилой.

Comment: НЕ совсем так. Союз должен быть не составной, а двойной, а двойного союза "пока...то" нет, есть "ЕСЛИ...ТО", "КОГДА...ТО". "Пока" - одиночный союз, здесь нет речи о второй части двойного союза, просто проверяем, можно ли "вынуть"придаточное.

Answer (score 1):

Конечно, будь начальник с ними до сих пор, они бы додумались до всего быстрее, но, пока меня не было, бедняга умер трагической смертью... Нужна, потому что выделяет придаточное.

Можно проверить, уберём придаточное: Конечно, будь начальник с ними до сих пор, они бы додумались до всего быстрее, но бедняга умер трагической смертью... Всё на месте, конструкция в норме, значит, запятые тоже на месте.

Answer (score 0):

Запятая в этом предложении после "но" нужна.